# How do I check for what color a jPanel is and how do I set the color of a jPanel

Tags: java, netbeans, colors

I have two main questions. The first is how can I set the background color of a jPanel and the second is how can I check the current color of a jPanel

I researched it a bit and I tried 
                 getContentPane().setBackground(jPanel8.blue);
to set the color of jPanel8 to blue but it doesn't work for some reason.

```
if(jPanel8 == white){
    getContentPane().setBackground(jPanel8.blue);
}else if(jPanel8 !== white)
```

My Ideal outcome is that where it says white it's checking is jPanel8 white, and where it say

getContentPane().setBackground(jPanel8.blue);

I want it to make jPanel8 blue.

Comment: [`JPanel#setBackground(Color)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setBackground(java.awt.Color))/[`JPanel#getBackground`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getBackground())

Comment: You'll also want to look at [`java.awt.Color`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html), in particular, look at the [`Color.equals(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to check JPanel Color : JPanel.getBackground();

How to set JPanel Color : JPanel.setBackground(Color);